# How to deploy factory contract with solidity @0.5.0 on Node.js

Tags: javascript, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, web3js

Repo: https://github.com/aljmiller87/ethereum-dispute-resolution

I have one solidity file @0.5.0 with a Factory Contract and a child contract. I am able to compile alright (though you'll note the trial and error in all the commented out lines in ethereum/compile.js).

Running `node ethereum/deploy.js` results in error.:

```
Attempting to deploy from account 0xff831110eeA8322639bee543AD1477AD9f472E22 
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas limit.
...
...
...
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:24059) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I've confirmed this contract code works in remix.
I've tried using `truffle-hdwallet-provider` on `0.0.3` and `0.0.5` (and updating the .deploy() and .send() arguments accordingly.

I've used this exact set up on another project @ solidity 0.4.17 and deploying works fine (although compile is different). Here's repo to previous project: https://github.com/aljmiller87/ethereum-kickstart

repo:https://github.com/aljmiller87/ethereum-dispute-resolution

ethereum/deploy.js

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const compiledContract = require('./build/ThreeJudge.json');

const compiledFactory = compiledContract.ContractFactory
const compiledFactoryABI = compiledFactory.abi;
const compiledFactoryBytecode = compiledFactory.evm.bytecode.object;


const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
    `${process.env.SEED_KEY}`,
    'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/ad66eb1337e043b2b50abe1323fff5f0'
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
    // Get account to deploy from
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log('Attempting to deploy from account', accounts[0]);

    // deploy code
    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(compiledFactoryABI)
    .deploy({ data: '0x' + compiledFactoryBytecode })
    .send({ gas: '1000000', from: accounts[0] });


    console.log('result address', result.options.address)
};

deploy();
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "kickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha test/ThreeJudge.test.js --timeout 10000",
    "test-local": "mocha test/ThreeJudge-local.test.js --timeout 10000",
    "dev": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "ganache-cli": "^6.5.0",
    "mocha": "^6.1.4",
    "next": "^4.1.4",
    "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.87.3",
    "solc": "0.5.2",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "0.0.5",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.37"
  }
}
```

Running `node ethereum/deploy.js` results in error.:

```
Attempting to deploy from account 0xff831110eeA8322639bee543AD1477AD9f472E22
(node:24059) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas limit.
    at Object.callback (/Users/alexmiller/Projects/solidity/threejudges/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:333:46)
    at sendTxCallback (/Users/alexmiller/Projects/solidity/threejudges/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:484:29)
    at /Users/alexmiller/Projects/solidity/threejudges/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/src/index.js:147:9
    at /Users/alexmiller/Projects/solidity/threejudges/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:172:9
    at /Users/alexmiller/Projects/solidity/threejudges/node_modules/async/internal/once.js:12:16
    at replenish (/Users/alexmiller/Projects/solidity/threejudges/node_modules/async/internal/eachOfLimit.js:61:25)
    at /Users/alexmiller/Projects/solidity/threejudges/node_modules/async/internal/eachOfLimit.js:71:9
    at eachLimit (/Users/alexmiller/Projects/solidity/threejudges/node_modules/async/eachLimit.js:43:36)
    at /Users/alexmiller/Projects/solidity/threejudges/node_modules/async/internal/doLimit.js:9:16
    at end (/Users/alexmiller/Projects/solidity/threejudges/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:147:5)
    at /Users/alexmiller/Projects/solidity/threejudges/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/provider.js:20:5
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/Users/alexmiller/Projects/solidity/threejudges/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:118:13)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (/Users/alexmiller/Projects/solidity/threejudges/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:76:20)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/Users/alexmiller/Projects/solidity/threejudges/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:422:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/Users/alexmiller/Projects/solidity/threejudges/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:615:14)
    at IncomingMessage._response.on (/Users/alexmiller/Projects/solidity/threejudges/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:567:23)
(node:24059) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:24059) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Also tried setting gas to 7000000. After 5 min waiting, nothing happens after initial console.log `Attempting to deploy from account 0x...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the issue was in the solidity code. I was attempting to keep an array of the Contract type, rather than the addresses of the contracts created.

Original:

```
contract ContractFactory {
    ThreeJudge[] public deployedContracts;

    function createContract(address payable _buyer, address payable _seller) public {
        ThreeJudge newContract = new ThreeJudge(_buyer, _seller);
        deployedContracts.push(newContract);
    }

    function getDeployedContracts() public view returns (ThreeJudge[] memory) {
        return deployedContracts;
    }
}

contract ThreeJudge {
...
```

Fix:

```
contract ContractFactory {
    address[] public deployedContracts;

    function createContract(address payable _buyer, address payable _seller) public {
        ThreeJudge newContract = new ThreeJudge(_buyer, _seller);
        deployedContracts.push(address(newContract));
    }

    function getCampaignsByAddress() public view returns (address[] memory) {
        return deployedContracts;
    }
}

contract ThreeJudge {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a clone factory contract instead of a new keyword as it is very cheap in terms of gas, Here is the link for the reference: [clone-factory](https://github.com/optionality/clone-factory) and why it is better ["Attack Of The Clones — How DDA Contracts Are So Cheap To Deploy"](https://blog.goodaudience.com/attack-of-the-clones-how-dda-contracts-are-so-cheap-to-deploy-f3cee9c7566)